# Datadog: Remap a field from an array inside an attribute

Tags: datadog, grok

The log has come into datadog as a JSON object and attributes have been parsed automatically.

Next I want to extract the owner field from an array nested in the JSON:

This syntax doesn't work does in datadog: `@detail.resources[0].tags.owner`

```json
{
  name: "example_name"
  detail: { 
    resources: [
     /*0*/ { tags: {owner: "test@test.com"}}, 
     /*1*/ { tags: {owner: "test@test.com"}}
    ]
}
```

This syntax doesn't work does in datadog: `@detail.resources[0].tags.owner`

each value in the array should have the same owner. How can I use datadog processors to remap the first found email from this array to another attribute called `@application.owner`? Do I have to unparse the JSON somehow and use a Grok Processor?